# reset counter of theorem after unnumbered section

Tags: numbering, theorems

At the moment I'm working on a bigger paper in which there will be exercises and solutions of these exercises at the end. The exercises are counted within chapters and the solutions will be in a chapter of their own, divided into unnumbered sections. Logically the solutions have to be numbered within these sections. Like

```
\chapter{chapter 1}
exercise 1

\chapter{chapter 2}
exercise 1

\chapter{solutions}
\section*{Solution to chapter 1}
solution 1
\section*{solution to chapter 2}
solution 1
```

Is there any way to get this? I don't want to reset the counter every time after the section. Obviously, the `counterwithin`-option does not work with unnumbered sections. I found a solution in which you had to redefine the section-command or hard-reset the counter at the end of every section, but I prefer not to do this. I hope for a solution, where I either redefine my solution-environment (which is currently just defined by newtheorem) or to write a command, that I can use after `\chapter`. Is there any way to realize this?

Comment: `\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\setcounter{solution}{0}}`  (untested as you didn't provide a suitable minimal example).

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but I found a very nice alternative, as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a good alternative. There exists a package `exsheets` which does exactly what I wanted. The only negative is, that this package will not be updated anymore (except for bugs). Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\counterwithin*{question}{chapter}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin,question/type=exam }

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter one}
\begin{question}
    Show $1=2$.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    Let $a\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. Then $a^2-a^2=a^2-a^2$, thus $a(a-a)=(a+a)(a-a)$ and $a=a+a$. By dividing by $a$ we get $1=2$.
\end{solution}
\chapter{chapter two}
\begin{question}
    Every chapter is trivial.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    Last chapter was trivial, this chapter is trivial. Thus, by induction, every chapter is trivial.
\end{solution}

\chapter*{Solution}
\section*{Solution of chapter one}
\printsolutions[chapter={1}]
\section*{Solution of chapter two}
\printsolutions[chapter={2}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note, that there is an official successor of `exsheets`: [`xsim`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Good to know